# What are square brackets used for, except for intervals?

Tags: analysis, notation

What is the meaning of the square brackets in the following proof?

${E(x) - E(-x) \over 2} = {1 \over 2}(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {x^n \over n!} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-x)^n \over n!}) = {1 \over 2}[\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{x^{2k} \over (2k)!} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{x^{2k+1} \over (2k+1)!} - (\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{x^{2k} \over (2k)!} - \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{x^{2k+1} \over (2k+1)!})] = {1 \over 2}2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{x^{2k+1} \over (2k+1)!} = sinh(x)$

Obviously it is not an interval and it doesn't have anything to do with integrals.

Comment: Just an alternative of (parentheses).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The square brackets here have the same meaning as regular parenthesis. Sometimes people use them in this manner for visual clarity.

Answer (score 4):

They're usually just used as another method of grouping, generally higher than parentheses. (Sometimes braces are also added to the hierarchy, but that seems to be less common.) That's the way they're used in your equation: They show that the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ applies to all four terms. It's less common, and I wouldn't expect the reader to recognize it without prompting, but I have seen it also used in the context of integral or fractional parts of a real number: $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$, $x - \lfloor{x}\rfloor$, etc. (It's my impression, though, that $\{x\}$ is the more common notation there.) In this particular example, though, it's definitely just grouping.